# Xcode with Core Data and ftp'ing data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

Disclaimer: I'm a relatively novice Xcode programmer writing a simple app for the iPhone.

What would be the best way to upload data to a server which is being stored in multiple models in Core Data?

I was thinking of writing the data to a file and then ftp'ing it to the server. Are there any better solutions to this? I don't strictly have to use FTP, but thought it would be simplier then say uploading via HTTP or using SCP.

Should I stream directly to the FTP server rather then outputing to a file first (if this is even possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection`. You will find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). On the server side it is enough to have a simple http form with POST. Works like a charm even with very big files.

It is not necessary to first store a copy of the file in the application's document directory. If the transfer gets interrupted you can always quickly recreate the file from core data.